# How to assert that all child nodes have a certain attribute value in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

Given the following partial XML document:

```
<section>
    <entry typeCode="DRIV">
        <act classCode="AT" moodCode="DEF">
            <statusCode code="completed"/>
        </act>
    </entry>
    <entry typeCode="DRIV">
        <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="DEF">
            <statusCode code="completed"/>
        </act>
    </entry>
    <entry typeCode="DRIV">
        <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="DEF">
            <statusCode code="completed"/>
        </act>
    </entry>
    <entry typeCode="DRIV">
        <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="DEF">
            <statusCode code="completed"/>
        </act>
    </entry>

    <section>
        <entry typeCode="DRIV">
            <act classCode="AT" moodCode="DEF">
                <statusCode code="completed"/>
            </act>
        </entry>
        <entry typeCode="DRIV">
            <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="DEF">
                <statusCode code="completed"/>
            </act>
        </entry>
    </section>
</section>
```

I want to assert that all of the  elements that are descendents of the outer `<section>` element, but not the inner `<section>` element, have for the `classCode` attribute the value `"ACT"`.

In other words, given the above example, I don't need to assert the value of the two `<act>` children in the second `<section>` element.  Also, there can be one or more nested `<entry>` elements (no maximum).

I tried the following XPath expression,

```
<xsl:when test="cda:section/cda:entry/cda:act//@classCode='ACT'"/>
```

If any of the `<act>` elements has a value for the attribute `classCode` other than `"ACT"`, the assertion should fail.  I am looking for advice on how to change my XPath expression to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just invert the condition:

```
<xsl:when test="not(cda:section/cda:entry/cda:act//@classCode != 'ACT')"/>
```

The expression inside `not()` will produce `true` if *any* `@classCode` will not be equal to `'ACT'`. It will only return `false` if *no* `@classCode` is equal to `'ACT'`. And then we invert that as well, and get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the context node is the outer `<section>`'s immediate parent, you can do this with the following test:

```
<xsl:when test="count(cda:section/cda:entry/cda:act) = count(cda:section/cda:entry/cda:act[@classCode = 'ACT'])">
    <foo/>
</xsl:when>
```

This works by counting the number of `<act>` elements belonging to `<entry>`s which are direct descendants of the `<section>` (anything in the child `<section>` is skipped).  It then counts the number of `<act>`s which have a `classCode` of "`ACT`" and sees if the two counts match.  Because it is impossible for a node to match the second count but not the first, you know that **all** non-nested descendant `<act>`s have the proper `classCode`.

Answer (score 1):

> If any of the `<act>` elements has a
>   value for the attribute `classCode`
>   other than `"ACT"`, the assertion
>   should fail.

Another variant that may be semantically more obvious:

```
count(cda:section/cda:entry/cda:act[@classCode != 'ACT']) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm.

```
<xsl:when test="cda:section/cda:entry/cda:act/@classcode = 'ACT'" />
```

Should do what you're looking for.

Comment: This test will return true if **any** `classCode` is "ACT".  The OP wants to test for **all** `classCode`s being "ACT".